# NSUserDefaults setObject and IntegerForKey, use on the same key, if not how can I workaround?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need to iterate through all the keys in my NSUserDefaults and transfer them to another format. Later I'll want to transfer them back, programatically.

I have a lot of keys and I have no way in my naming convention or by other means to determine if I used setObject or setInteger etc.

If I use setObject will this enable me to use integerForKey on that key ?

If I can't want can I use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure using setObject will allow you to use integerForKey later.

Another way to go could be by adding a plist to your project and store everything in there. It's basically the same as NSUserDefaults is doing, only you'll be doing it all by hand. You can just read the contents of a plist to either an NSArray or an NSDictionary (whichever you chose to construct it with in the first place) and then access the members you need from that object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I recommend not using PLIST's for these kind of problems at all. It's bad practice, and if you "need to" use one, there's probably a fault in your design somewhere and you should rethink the implementation.

Comment: Awarded for the for the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not be able to get the correct objects if you use `integerForKey:`. However you could get the correct objects if you use `objectForKey:`. This is because if you had used `setInteger:forKey:`, it automatically calls `setObject:forKey:`. So, there will be an object for the key. So what you have to do is iterate through the keys, get the objects using `objectForKey:` and convert it to the data type that you want.

Comment: It does seem to have worked. But I do set a default value, I guess thats probably the reason ?

Comment: It should work either way. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setInteger:forKey: